# prevent element from from being tabbed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have following html markup:

```
    <tr class="table_row">
    <td tabindex="-1" class="delete_row"><button class="btn btn-small btn-danger">X</button></td>
    <td>
        <span class="row0" contenteditable="true">Text 1</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span id="tourCellData" class="row0" contenteditable="true">Text 2</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="row0" contenteditable="true">Text 3</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="row0" contenteditable="true">Text 4</span>
    </td>
            <td>
        <span class="row0" contenteditable="true">Text 5</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'm looking for ways to prevent the  element with the class of ".delete_row" from being tabbed. I have searched StackOverflow and found that 'tabindex="-1"' should do the work. But it is not working for me.

I found a solution with jQuery:

```
$("#parentSelector").on("focus", ".delete_row", function () {
    $(this).next().find("span").focus();
});
```

Is there an alternative Solution without using jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hGPAp/8/)

Add the `tabindex="-1"` to your button element

```
 <td class="delete_row"><button tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">X</button></td>
```